# Testnet Blockchain Sync

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, ropsten, testrpc-to-ropsten

I used geth for windows and ran it as a desktop app. Not sure if I am connected to public blockchain or testnet. How do I check which network is getting synced. ?

(I want to download ropsten testnet blockchain in windows machine.  I clicked on geth exec file and geth started to download blocks. I am a beginner. Please help me with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify network type using three popular methods:

1. Your geth client you will find below one line,

   > INFO [02-16|22:25:29] Initialising Ethereum protocol versions="[63 62]" **network=1**
2. Attach your ipc or rpc by using below command:

   > geth attach {RPC-IP/IPC File}

   Geth will open shell, then type

> $> admin.nodeInfo

```
{
  enode: "enode://XXXXXXXXXYZZZZZZ@Z.Z.Z.214:30303",
  id: "<ID>",
  ip: "Z.Z.Z.214",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30303",
  name: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2",
  ports: {
    discovery: 30303,
    listener: 30303
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: <DIFF>,
      genesis: "<BLOCK>",
      head: "<HEAD>",
      network: 1
    },
    shh: {
      maxMessageSize: 1048576,
      minimumPoW: 0.2,
      version: "5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

3. Geth client command: If your not specify any thing in geth console. By default it will connect to main net. Check geth client command.

> ```
> --networkid value Network identifier (integer, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten, 4=Rinkeby) (default: 1)
> ```